# blueimp file upload from an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, blueimp

Perhaps this is the wrong way to build this, but I have a lot of information being served to my webpage and so I have been pulling bits as needed by the user using Ajax. One of the elements I would like to retrieve is a blueimp file uploader. All seems good except for the message I get from the console when I try to add a file.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseMetaData' of undefined

The processing image appears, but then ... nothing.

If anyone could clue me in as to why I am getting this error, and perhaps how to fix it, I would be very grateful.

**What the Ajax writes to screen**

In the header

```html
<!-- Bootstrap styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Generic page styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fileUpload/css/style.css">
<!-- blueimp Gallery styles 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">-->
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fileUpload/css/jquery.fileupload.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fileUpload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
 <!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="fileUpload/css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css"></noscript>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="fileUpload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
```

Ajax output

```html
 
<!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
<form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <!-- The global file processing state -->
            <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- The global progress state -->
        <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- The extended global progress state -->
            <div class="progress-extended"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
</form>

    

<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="fileUpload/js/main.js"></script>
<!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE 8 and IE 9 -->
<!--[if (gte IE 8)&(lt IE 10)]>
<script src="js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Hopefully that's what you need.

On closer inspection I think this might be the part that's causing some of my issues:

```html
loadImageMetaData: function (data, options) {
                if (options.disabled) {
                    return data;
                }
                var that = this,
                    dfd = $.Deferred();
                loadImage.parseMetaData(data.files[data.index], function (result) {
                    $.extend(data, result);
                    dfd.resolveWith(that, [data]);
                }, options);
                return dfd.promise();
            },
```

Comment: can we see the code please . Also how about you check this page : https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image

Comment: I will put in what I can, but it pulls from lots of places. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: It's bog standard to start with. I just need it to load and run first.

Comment: The ajax is called from a different directory. When I display the $_SERVER info the SCRIPT_FILENAME shows within that folder. Could this prevent the script finding the meta data?

Comment: add this file https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.all.min.js and you should be through

Comment: Thanks once more for you response. Totally appreciated. I tried your suggestion and my application could not find that page so it generated a 404 error. Plus it seems very close to blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js which is a file the page is referencing (seemingly successfully). The script is still not loading once I have selected a file (or two). It work fine if I call it directly, but the Ajax is really messing it up. I feel certain it is looking for the meta data about the image(s) its trying to preview looking in the wrong place...or I just don't have a clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding each of these files separately

```
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.js"></script>
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image-ios.js"></script>
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image-orientation.js"></script>
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image-meta.js"></script>
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image-exif.js"></script>
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image-exif-map.js"></script>

-- my fault was that I should have added `https://` in front of  [BlueImp][1]  . Apologies for the same
```

Comment: Sadly it's still giving me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseMetaData' of undefined " and stopping. Do you happen to know what parseMetaData is/does/configured?

Comment: f you include the Load Image Exif Parser extension, the parseMetaData callback data contains the additional property exif if Exif data could be found in the given image.
The exif object stores the parsed Exif tags. Straight From https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image

Comment: I appreciate all your help, but what you are talking about is beyond my knowledge of jquery and this script. I have explored, tested and retested til i'm blue in the face and still no joy, so I think I will run the script without pulling from ajax. I know it works that way for me. If only I could show you directly what I'm working on I know you would work it out in a tick, but naturally it would give you access to all sorts of things that my employer would not want in the public domain. Thanks for everything.

Comment: no issues. just let me know if I could be of any help.

Comment: I wanted to do the same thing. Even though I couldn't really fire my own AJAX call I managed to be able to fire the `data.submit()` at will. If you want an example let me know.

Comment: @Satya, Seems I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650465/how-do-i-fix-orientation-upload-image-before-saving-in-folder-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're not loading load-image-all in a modal or the like, this was my problem. No matter how long I waited, 90% of the time I would get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseMetaData' of undefined

The other 10% of the time it miraculously worked...

So, again - putting scripts on the main template was my fix.

Comment: **This** is the correct answer! You have to make sure you're not including the scripts from within a closure, like including these scripts in a file that is dynamically loaded through ajax (or any other) or even a $(document).ready() call...

Comment: @Lauri Elias, Seems I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650465/how-do-i-fix-orientation-upload-image-before-saving-in-folder-javascript

Answer (score 1):

*jquery.fileuploader-image* receives the loadImage (around line 41):

```
}(function ($, loadImage) {
```

if the *load-image.all.min.js* was not included before that script, this error will occur (around line 275):

```
loadImage.parseMetaData
```

Comment: OK! Mind blown. I'll check that out. Strangely I think I understand this post. LOL

Comment: @Bruno Reis, Seems I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650465/how-do-i-fix-orientation-upload-image-before-saving-in-folder-javascript